# Passport does not send scopes

Tags: express, passport-facebook

I do pass email as scope as seen here:

```
router.get(keys.facebookCallbackURL, passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    scope: ['public_profile', 'email'], 
    failureRedirect: '/', 
    session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
        //...
    }
);
```

Generated url is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&client_id=123977854776367
```

which does not ask user to grant email, but when I append `&scope=email%2Cpublic_profile` to url manually it does.

Like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&client_id=123977854776367&scope=email%2Cpublic_profile
```

Why scopes are not appended to url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was adding scopes to the wrong route.

```
router.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile", "email"]
  })
);
```